# Drupal Commons Completely private posts

Tags: 7

How can I give users the opportunity to make few posts completely private (i.e. visible only to themselves)? I'd like to do this with a *make this post private - only for me* checkbox.

Comment: If nobody else can see it, might as well delete it, I don't see the point of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

[Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access)

> This module allows you to manage permissions for content types by role
>   and author. It allows you to specifiy custom view, edit and delete
>   permissions for each content type. Optionally you can enable per
>   content access settings, so you can customize the access for each
>   content node.

Or you can do by allow permission to allow specific viewer/role

Comment: Really don't understand the except that this module does. I can do it easily from *roles*, admin>people>permissions>roles. What I'd like to do is to make certain posts (*nodes*) private.